# OAuth2.0 Госуслуги и Scala

Tags: scala, oauth2, playframework, есиа

В запросе необходимо сформировать некий client_secret! Вот что описано в мaнуале: 
client_secret – подпись запроса в формате PKCS#7 detached signature в кодировке UTF8 от значений следующих параметров HTTP–запроса: scope, timestamp, client_id, state (без разделителей). должен быть закодирован в формате base64 url safe. Используемый для проверки подписи сертификат должен быть предварительно зарегистрирован в ЕСИА и привязан к учетной записи системы-клиента в ЕСИА. ЕСИА поддерживает сертификаты в формате X.509. ЕСИА поддерживает алгоритмы формирования электронной подписи RSA с длиной ключа 2048 и алгоритмом криптографического хэширования SHA-256, а также алгоритм электронной подписи ГОСТ Р 34.10-2001 и алгоритм криптографического хэширования ГОСТ Р 34.11-94.;

Есть уже алгоритм
[Аутентификация через ЕСИА OAuth2](https://habr.com/post/276313/)

Я знаю что в Scala можно подключить класс Java, но ищу более лаконичного решения!

Вопрос:

1) Как реализовать получение client_secret на Scala, не прибегая к классу Java!

2) Сертификат уже есть и в коде я его подключаю(могу вывести его в консоль ), не могу понять логику связывания его с значениями параметров HTTP-запроса?

P.S. Возможно есть какие то готовые библиотеки на Scala? Я понимаю что можно подключить библиотеки Java! Но я не нашел альтернативу коду:

```
ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(msg);
SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, true);
CmsSigner cmsSigner = new CmsSigner(signerCert);
signedCms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner);
signedCms.Encode();
```

Так как эти библиотеки не подключаются, а альтернативные по схожим методам выдают совсем другие результаты!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда-то давным-давно реализовывал похожую задачу, и **НЕ** на скале. Поэтому полного ответа я Вам дать не смогу, скорее как напутствие. Сперва хотел написать как комментарий, но не уместился по объему, поэтому не судите строго.

**Первый вопрос:**

Для получения `client_secret` нужно просто взять значения ваших `scope`, `timestamp`, `client_id` и `state`, привести их к строке и сконкатенировать. Без пробелов и прочих разделителей. Прям банально:

```
val clientSecret = scope + timestamp + clientId + state
```

Дальше нужно это все подписать. Вот тут я не скажу что лучше использовать на скале, может меня кто-то поправит, кто лучше разбирается. Подозреваю что можно использовать [javax.crypto](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/package-summary.html). Да, класс не скаловский, а джавовский, но зато стандартный.
Я тогда использовал консольную утилиту [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/). В скале консольные процессы можно вызывать через `ProcessBuilder` и `Process`. Сам вызов сейчас уже не скажу, код остался на старой работе и доступа сейчас до него уже нет, но помню, что встроенный в утилиту `help` и немного времени помогут сформировать правильный вызов.

Тут надо вывести что получилось на экран, так как `OpenSSL` сохранит подпись в файл, и в начале и конце добавит к ней что-то вроде `----- RSA BEGIN -----` и `----- RSA END -----`. От этого надо избавиться.

Теперь самое простое. Нужно просто зашифровать все в `Base64`, например так:
Опять java, да :)

```
  //Признаюсь, сплагиатил с примера на хабре по ссылке в вопросе
  import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
  import java.util.Base64

  val replaced = signedClientSecret map {
    case '-' => '+'
    case '_' => '/'
    case x => x
  }
  val bytes = replaced getBytes StandardCharsets.UTF_8
  val b64 = Base64.getEncoder encode bytes
  val str = new String(b64)
  val clientSecret = str + (str.length % 4 match {
    case 2 => "=="
    case 3 => "="
    case _ => ""
  })
```

`client_secret` готов.

**Второй вопрос:**
Тут все просто, сертификат не надо прицеплять к `HTTP` запросу. Надо заранее связаться с техподдержкой ЕСИА, отправить им сертификат и попросить привязать его к Вашей учетной записи. А к запросу надо прицеплять уже `client_secret` в виде `GET` параметра, как то так:

`https://esia.gosuslugi.ru/aas/oauth2/ac?client_secret=SGVsbG8gd29ybGQh&<тут еще какие-то GET параметры, не помню>`

**P.S.** Удобно для этих целей использовать самоподписанный сертификат, так как КриптоПРОшный гененрит слишком длинный `client_secret`, в нашем случае было около 4к символов. В итоге авторизация через `IE` не работала, там `IE` обрезал слишком длинные `GET` запросы, отрезая половину параметров и пол подписи, делая ее не валидной.
Так же можно выпустить сертификат со сроком жизни более одного года.
Ещё КриптоПРОшный сертификат не удобно использовать с `OpenSSL`, но у них там есть своя консольная утилита, так что это решаемо.

Все это понятно, в ущерб безопасности. Стоит или нет - решать Вам.

**P.P.S** Как я сказал дело было уже давно, и может быть некоторые советы, вроде предыдущего уже не работают, надо проверять.

**P.P.P.S** Писал по памяти, не факт что все вот прям хоп и с первого раза заработает. Как я сказал тут скорее напутствие, чем готовое решение. 

**P.P.P.P.S** Если я все правильно понял, то чтоб приведенный Вами код заработал, нужно подключить [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/)

Comment: Добрый день! Благодарю за развернутый ответ! Буду эксперементировать, по ходу буду держать в курсе дела:)